# Android SDK directory

Tags: android, sdk, expo

I wanted to use `Expo` for React Native and somehow I couldn't load the project on my Android phone;
So I decided to use the `emulator`. But when I installed Android Studio, it says SDK is missing then it says that the SDK is already installed but the directory isn't the default one
I don't know what to do anymore and I'll appreciate it if somebody helped me with this issue.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

Answer (score 0):

1. Why you can‘t install your app on your device?
2. Can you create a device in the avd ?

Comment: I really have no idea what is avd :/ and about the first question; I installed it completely, actually these are screenshots from the app. I just cannot connect the expo app or start an android project ! any suggestions?

Comment: Can you start the android emulator?

Comment: No... It says " android emulator not found "